# llist index out of range in python

Tags: python, linux, loops, ubuntu, compiler-errors

```
def Entekhab3_fun():
    h = 0
    Max = 1
    while(h <= 10):
        if(Montakhabha[h] == None):
            break
        elif(Montakhabha[h] > Max):
            Max = Montakhabha[h]
        elif(Montakhabha[h] == Max):
            Max = Montakhabha[h]
        else:
            Max = Max
        h += 1
    return(Max)
```

This is part of my code that compiler refers to and I can't understand what's wrong with it, but when i compile it, it says:

> indexerror: list index out of range

Comment: what is `Montakhabha` here ?

Comment: Could you please provide the `Montakhabha` input and specify which line is giving the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO - as you already post: this is only a _part_ of your code. And also this is only a part of the error message. Usually, these messages tell you exactly _where_ the error was thrown. This information would be important to us, too. And without knowing `Montakhabha` and it's length, no one will be able to say much about your issue...

Comment: It seems that `Montakhabha` list is smaller than 11 elements

Comment: its a list that give it values with another while and the range is 10. but there isnt sure thing that all 10 indexes will be filled. it depends on the inputs

Comment: You are actually trying to access 11 elements, not 10 (numbers start from 0, so, from 0 to 10 you have 11 elements). Probably enough to change 'h <= 10' to 'h < 10'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only possible reason is that `Montakhabha` has less than 11 elements. Be careful that your condition is `h <= 10`, so you are checking `Montakhabha[10]` too in your code.

The safest would be to change that to

```
while h < len(Montakhabha)
```

some side notes:

- the first check should probably be `continue` instead of `break` (as should the last `Max=Max` assignment).
- use `x is None` instead of `x==None`. It is safe because `None` is a singleton value.
- 2nd and 3rd condition do the same thing

Overall, seems that what you are trying to do is

```
max_value = 0
for element Montakhabha:
    if element > max_value:
         max_value = element
```

Comment: I'd also add that the last `elif` and `else` are totally useless.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, your notes were very useful. It actually worked